# get city name by parsing in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

From this url:

> http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes?lat=19.0176560&lng=72.8561780

I want is city name that is mumbai can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have parsed out the latitude and longitude, you can use the [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to translate that location to [meta data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKPlacemark) about that location.  In that meta data, you will find the city name that you are after.

**Update**

Have a look at the Apple [CurrentAddress](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app, this has an example of how you use the [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).